# Dart: Adding child elements to DivElement programmatically

Tags: dart, dart-html

Say I want to add a `ButtonElement` to a `DivElement` programmatically, such that the resultant HTML is:

```html
<div class="blah">
    <input type="button" name="whatever" value="Push Me!" />
</div>
```

In Dart, I see several methods on the `DivElement` class, and I'm not sure which one is appropriate for which context:

```dart
ButtonElement button = constructButtonElement();
DivElement div = constructDiv();

div.add(button);
div.nodes.add(button);
div.children.add(button);
// ???
```

Same goes for any other kind of container: `BodyElement`, `SpanElement`, etc. **What's the correct way to dynamically add DOM elements to parent containers?**

Answer (score 7):

I prefer working with DOM elements using general Dart methods and operations. So, to add a button to a div that is then attached to the body, I would do the following:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var div = new DivElement();
  var button = new ButtonElement()
    ..id = 'foo'
    ..text = 'Foo';
  div.children.add(button);
  document.body.children.add(div);
}
```

This creates a `ButtonElement` with an `id` and a `text`, appends it to a `DivElement`'s `children`, and appends the `DivElement` to the document body.